# Problem with invites command (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to make an invites command on `discord.js` but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
        var targetUser = null;
        var isAnotherUserLookup = false;
        if(message.mentions.members.first() != null)
        {
            targetUser = message.mentions.members.first();
            isAnotherUserLookup = true;
        }
        else
            targetUser = message.member;

        message.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then
        (invites =>
            {var targetUser = null;
        var isAnotherUserLookup = false;
        if(message.mentions.members.first() != null)
        {
            targetUser = message.mentions.members.first().user;
            console.log(targetUser.user);
            isAnotherUserLookup = true;
        }
        else
            targetUser = message.author;

        message.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then
        (invites =>
            {
                const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === targetUser.id);
                var userInviteCount = 0;

                    if(isAnotherUserLookup)
                        message.channel.send(`User _${targetUser.username}_ has invited ${userInviteCount} user(s) to this server.`);

                    else
                        message.reply(`You have invited ${userInviteCount} user(s) to this server. Keep up the good work!`);
          return;
            }
        )
            }
        )
    }
```

And it keeps on coming up with the message but I have 0 invites.

I have looked over my code a few times, tried changing things up and overall nothing worked, I have reached out before if I am sure but that never worked. If I could get an answer on what is the problem and how to fix it that would be great.

Comment: Still requesting help, please.

Comment: Why are you requesting invites twice? The second section is a duplicate of the first.